# Why am I getting an error in int map operation during firebase connection? as String' is not a subtype of type 'int'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

during firebase connection, I get an error **type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'**

```
class _VeriTabaniState extends State<VeriTabani> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildBody(context, sahteSnapshot);
  }

  Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context, List<Map> snapshot) {
    return ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
      //buildListItem ztn bir liste, children içine alır direk
      children:
          //sahte datalardan gelen herşey için döndüreceğim
          //buildListItem'ı creat method ile oluşturdum
          snapshot
              .map<Widget>((data) => _buildListItem(context, data))
              .toList(),
    );
  }

  _buildListItem(BuildContext context, Map data) {
    //sahtelerden her gelen için yeni bir kayıt üretecek
    final kayitWidget = Kayit.fromMap(data);
    return Padding(
      //biz bunlara tıklarız mıklarız, hangisinin olduğunu anlamak için key
      key: ValueKey(kayitWidget.okulisim),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.2),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(kayitWidget.okulisim),
          trailing: Text(kayitWidget.sayi.toString()),
          //firebase'e yollayacağız
          onTap: () => {},
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

//sahte veriler oluşturalım
final sahteSnapshot = [
  {"okulisim": "Sau", "sayi": "1"},
  {"okulisim": "Metu", "sayi": "2"},
  {"okulisim": "Kou", "sayi": "3"},
  {"okulisim": "Boun", "sayi": "4"},
];

class Kayit {
  String okulisim;
  String sayi;
  DocumentReference reference;

  //kayit icin bir constructer oluşturalım
  //fb icin çok kullanılan bir yapısı var bunların
  Kayit.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {this.reference})
      : assert(map["okulisim"] != null),
        assert(map["sayi"] != null),
        okulisim = map["okulisim"],
        sayi = map["sayi"];

  //dbdeki anlık değisimler
  Kayit.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : this.fromMap(snapshot.data(), reference: snapshot.reference);

  @override
  String toString() => "Kayıt<$okulisim : $sayi>";
}
```

is actually where I get the int String error:

```
Kayit.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {this.reference})
      : assert(map["okulisim"] != null),
        assert(map["sayi"] != null),
        okulisim = map["okulisim"],
        sayi = map["sayi"];
```

and it fixes when I make the variable int to String

```
class Kayit {
  String okulisim;
  String sayi;
  DocumentReference reference;

  //kayit icin bir constructer oluşturalım
  //fb icin çok kullanılan bir yapısı var bunların
  Kayit.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {this.reference})
      : assert(map["okulisim"] != null),
        assert(map["sayi"] != null),
        okulisim = map["okulisim"],
        sayi = map["sayi"];
```

How?

Comment: New Year with new questions 

Answer (score 3):

> String' is not a subtype of type 'int'

You are retrieving a `String` from the database and assigning it to an `int`, thus you get the above error. To solve this either change your variable to type `String` or save an `int` in the database:

```
final sahteSnapshot = [
  {"okulisim": "Sau", "sayi": 1},
  {"okulisim": "Metu", "sayi": 2},
  {"okulisim": "Kou", "sayi": 3},
  {"okulisim": "Boun", "sayi": 4},
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your model is not correct here. `sayi` needs to be `int`, not `String`:

```
class Kayit {
    String okulisim;
    int sayi;
    DocumentReference reference;
```